# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rake' <=10.4.2.>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tried to bundle install in my first ruby project, doing a tutorial so i'm pretty new to all of this coding stuff. I was following part of the tutorial and everything was going fine until I encountered this:

> Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
>   server certificate B: certificate verify failed https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2
>   An error occured while installing rake <10.4.2>, and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling.

Please explain in layman terms

Comment: have you tried `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`?

Answer (score 0):

`Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2' succeeds before bundling.`

Type `gem install rake -v '10.4.2` in to your command line and it'll install the rake gem.

Gems are simply other Ruby programs you can add to use within your program. See here: https://rubygems.org/ and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems